# Getting the current URL within the View layer in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I've read some previous questions here and on other sites, but being new to ASP.net and MVC I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the information presented.

I want/need/was told to get the current URL of the page I'm on through the View layer, and use that information to apply an id to a li tag allowing for specific css. We've moved our left navigation bar from being embedded in every single page (done by a previous co-op) to putting the list in a partial view that I'm going to call on all of the required pages. Styling requirements for the site have a specific highlight on the left navigation a tag of the page the user is currently on.

Some of the examples I've read including using:

```
<%= Request.Url.PathAndQuery %>

Request.Url.ToString() or Request.Url.AbsoluteUri

var request = HttpContext.Current.Request
```

but I know not all of them can be used in the View layer. What would be the best approach? Are there any tutorials that I haven't been able to find yet that anyone could recommend?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It probably isn't the best idea, in my opinion, to use the URL for this.

Instead, a quick and easy way to achieve this is to use `ViewContext.RouteData` that will contain values for both the controller and action of the current request. It can be accessed from the view layer easily.

```
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString()
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString()
```

So in your view you could do something like

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString() == "ControllerName" ? "active" : "")"><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
</ul>
```

You could push it further to make it prettier, but you get the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for! (Edit: Whoops, you showed me the CSS part)

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for a solution on this for asp.net 3.0 and found the following to give direct access to the URL path (what page you're currently loading/showing):

```
ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Path
```

I'm using this in an if statement to decide dynamically between different View Imports, works very well.